# Como converto o tamanho de um arquivo em bytes para KB, MB, GB, TB, etc?

Tags: c#, .net

Estou pegando o tamanho de arquivos para exibir na tela:

```cs
new FileInfo(arquivo).Length
```

Só que esta propriedade me retorna o total de bytes... Eu gostaria de exibir em um formato que desse para entender, por exemplo, ao invés de `2147483647` quero mostrar `2 GB`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Qual a razão de fazer uma pergunta e responder a si mesmo?

Comment: @GabrielSantos [Is it ok to ask and answer your own questions?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). [Apoiamos a reescrita de perguntas ou respostas do Stack Overflow](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/q/1/40). Razão: Gerar conteúdo em PT, essa é a rezão desse site existir.

Comment: @Bacco tem que esperar 2 dias para poder aceitar a própria resposta. Eu esperei ~3.

Comment: Alem disso a resposta do talles não suporta o tipo double, e não mostra `1 B`, o minimo que mostra é em `KB`. A performance é melhor mas não significante. Consigo rodar minha solução 1 milhão de vezes em meio segundo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe várias formas de fazer isto. Uma que me chamou atenção foi o [método do deepee1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4975942/340760). Fiz um pequeno ajuste e coloquei este método em uma classe de *extension methods*.

```cs
public static partial class NumericExtender
{
    private static IList<string> fileSizeUnits;

    static NumericExtender()
    {
        fileSizeUnits =
            new List<string>() { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retorna o valor formatado como tamanho de arquivo (KB, MB, GB...).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="totalBytes">Total de bytes do arquivo.</param>
    /// <param name="precision">Número de casas decimais para exibir.</param>
    /// <returns>Tamanho do arquivo formatado.</returns>
    public static string ToFileSize(this double totalBytes, int precision = 2)
    {
        if (totalBytes <= 0)
            return String.Format("0 {0}", fileSizeUnits[0]);

        double bytes = Math.Abs(totalBytes);
        int place = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Log(bytes, 1024)));
        if (place > fileSizeUnits.Count - 1)
            place = fileSizeUnits.Count - 1;

        double num = Math.Round(bytes / Math.Pow(1024, place), precision);
        return String.Format("{0} {1}", Math.Sign(totalBytes) * num, fileSizeUnits[place]);
    }
}
```

E fiz um método de teste:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void ToFileSize()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("0 B", Int32.MinValue.ToFileSize());
    Assert.AreEqual("0 B", UInt32.MinValue.ToFileSize());
    Assert.AreEqual("0 B", Int64.MinValue.ToFileSize());
    Assert.AreEqual("0 B", UInt64.MinValue.ToFileSize());
    Assert.AreEqual("0 B", Double.MinValue.ToFileSize());

    Assert.AreEqual("2 GB", Int32.MaxValue.ToFileSize());
    Assert.AreEqual("4 GB", UInt32.MaxValue.ToFileSize());
    Assert.AreEqual("8 EB", Int64.MaxValue.ToFileSize());
    Assert.AreEqual("16 EB", UInt64.MaxValue.ToFileSize());
    Assert.AreEqual("1.48701690847778E+284 YB", Double.MaxValue.ToFileSize());

    Assert.AreEqual("1.24 KB", 1270.ToFileSize());
    Assert.AreEqual("1.24023 KB", 1270.ToFileSize(5));
}
```

Answer (score 10):

### Performance!

Para quem, por qualquer motivo que seja, precise de que essa formatação tenha uma boa performance basta utilizar constantes e [operadores de deslocamento binário (*shift*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xt18et0d.aspx):

```
public static string TamanhoAmigavel(long bytes)
{
    if (bytes < 0) throw new ArgumentException("bytes");

    double humano;
    string sufixo;

    if (bytes >= 1152921504606846976L) // Exabyte (1024^6)
    {
        humano = bytes >> 50;
        sufixo = "EB";
    }
    else if (bytes >= 1125899906842624L) // Petabyte (1024^5)
    {
        humano = bytes >> 40;
        sufixo = "PB";
    }
    else if (bytes >= 1099511627776L) // Terabyte (1024^4)
    {
        humano = bytes >> 30;
        sufixo = "TB";
    }
    else if (bytes >= 1073741824) // Gigabyte (1024^3)
    {
        humano = bytes >> 20;
        sufixo = "GB";
    }
    else if (bytes >= 1048576) // Megabyte (1024^2)
    {
        humano = bytes >> 10;
        sufixo = "MB";
    }
    else if (bytes >= 1024) // Kilobyte (1024^1)
    {
        humano = bytes;
        sufixo = "KB";
    }
    else return bytes.ToString("0 B"); // Byte

    humano /= 1024;
    return humano.ToString("0.## ") + sufixo;
}
```

**Por quê o ganho de performance?**

- Utilizando constantes você evita o cálculo em tempo de execução dos [prefixos binários](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefixo_bin%C3%A1rio).
- A operação de [deslocamento de bits](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_bin%C3%A1ria#Shift) é, *teoricamente**, menos custosa para o processador que a operações matemáticas *comuns*:

> On simple low-cost processors, typically, bitwise operations are substantially faster than division, several times faster than multiplication, and sometimes significantly faster than addition. While modern processors usually perform addition and multiplication just as fast as bitwise operations due to their longer instruction pipelines and other architectural design choices, bitwise operations do commonly use less power because of the reduced use of resources.
>   ([fonte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation))

Traduzindo:

> Em processadores de baixo custo, usualmente as operações em bits são substancialmente mais rápidas do que a divisão, muitas vezes mais rápidas que a multiplicação, e algumas vezes mais rápidas do que a adição. Apesar de os processadores modernos normalmente fazerem a adição e multiplicação tão rapidamente quanto as operações em bits devido às filas de instrução mais longas e outras decisões de arquitetura, as operações em bits normalmente usam menos energia por demandarem uma quantidade reduzida de recursos.

***** <sup>Teoricamente pois na prática o compilador pode otimizar seu código.</sup>

---

Na [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/281640) da resposta citada pelo @BrunoLM existe uma [outra solução interessante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281716) utilizando a DLL [Shlwapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb759844.aspx) do Windows:

```
[DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern long StrFormatByteSize(long fileSize, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]StringBuilder buffer, int bufferSize);

public static string StrFormatByteSize(long filesize)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(11);
    StrFormatByteSize(filesize, sb, sb.Capacity);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Na maioria dos casos seria um exagero importar uma DLL externa para somente esta função. Mas *provavelmente* (alguém confirma?) a formatação feita por essa função é exatamente a utilizada pelo Windows Explorer; em algum cenário essa consistência pode ser útil ou até mesmo necessária.

Comment: Já que o foco é performance, uma outra otimização que pode ser feita é a seguinte: `if (bytes >= 1024)` é o mesmo que `if (bytes >> 10)`, afinal e o número é maior ou igual a 1024, então algum bit após o décimo é 1 e o resultado do *shift* será não nulo. Assim é uma comparação a menos e permite ao compilador reutilizar a subexpressão `bytes >> 10` nos dois pontos em que ela aparece. O mesmo se aplica ao 20, 30, etc.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal, realmente haveria um ganho de performance, mas o C# não interpreta outro tipo que não `bool` em uma expressão condicional. O operador `>>` vai retornar um `long` e o C# irá forçar você a fazer a comparação nesse retorno (*Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'bool'*). Mas não deixa de ser uma boa dica para quem está aproveitando a resposta para outra linguagem, como C++ :-)